# Max and min date in a dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

What is the most pythonic way to find the max and min dates across a dictionary of dataframes that each have a datetime index?  For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index =  [datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 2, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 6, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 13, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 26, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 2, 0, 0)],
                    data = {'bee' : [5, 3, 1, 0, 2],
                           'an' : [2,3,2,2,7]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(index =  [datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 2, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 6, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 13, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 26, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 2, 0, 0)],
                    data = {'bee' : [15, 2, 5, 0, 2],
                           'an' : [1,1,2,7,7]})

df_dict = {'df1':df1, 'df2':df2}

df_dict['df1']
```

Output:

```
index       an  bee
2016-07-02  2   5
2016-08-06  3   3
2016-09-13  2   1
2016-10-26  2   0
2016-11-02  7   2
```

And

```
df_dict['df2']
```

Output

```
index       an  bee
2015-07-02  1   15
2015-08-06  1   2
2015-09-13  2   5
2015-10-26  7   0
2015-11-02  7   2
```

So, I would like to find the max date of `df_dict`, which should be 2016-11-02, and the min date of `df_dict`, which is 2015-07-02.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `max` of each `max`'s, and `min` of each `min`'s

```
max(max(v.index) for k,v in df_dict.items())
min(min(v.index) for k,v in df_dict.items())

2016-11-02 00:00:00
2015-07-02 00:00:00
```

---

Adding @Wen suggestion, if you won't use both `k` and `v`, you can do

```
max(max(v.index) for _,v in df_dict.items())
```

or even

```
max(max(df_dict[k].index) for k in df_dict.keys())
```

Comment: This works, thanks!  I'm new to python, can you help me understand why it needs two arguments, k and v or _ and v? Where can I find out more information about the strategy you used, what key terms should I google?

Comment: Ah, k is for "key" and v is for "value" in looping through a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

By using `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat(df_dict).index.get_level_values(1).max()
Out[159]: Timestamp('2016-11-02 00:00:00')
pd.concat(df_dict).index.get_level_values(1).min()
Out[160]: Timestamp('2015-07-02 00:00:00')
```